# Draw with canvas.draw() a custom class

Tags: android, class, canvas, ondraw

Im using Canvas to draw what i call a "label" in my app. This "label" has a round shape, an icon and text. I'm currently calling the method canvas.draw() and I just put the params to draw this.
Since my app needs to handle a lot of those labels, i need to create a Class to handle the icon and the text of the label instead of calling the method canvas.draw(Text, Bitmap, paint...).
Is there a way I can do that?
I will post some of the code:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
canvas.draw(Bitmap myBitmap);
canvas.draw(String myText);
```

And so on.
What i need to do is to use a class as a param to draw with canvas.

```
canvas.draw(MyCustomClass labelBathroom);
```

Assuming that MyCustomClass has all the properties and methods required.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap this up in either a `View` or a `Drawable`.